# Monotouch sqlite crash when inserting a lot of rows

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios

I've an app built with xamarin iOS. The database is sqlite. Both in simulator and device, after the app starts to work on data, it gives me a SIGSEGV error.

Stacktrace:

at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Data.Sqlite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_prepare (intptr,intptr,int,intptr&,intptr&) 
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SQLite3.Prepare (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection,string,Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteStatement,uint,string&) [0x00044] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLite3.cs:268
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.BuildNextCommand () [0x00019] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteCommand.cs:230
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatement (int) [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteCommand.cs:264
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatement (int) 
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult () [0x000cc] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteDataReader.cs:896
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader..ctor (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand,System.Data.CommandBehavior) [0x00051] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteDataReader.cs:89
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader..ctor (Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand,System.Data.CommandBehavior) 
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior) [0x00006] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteCommand.cs:539
  at Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteCommand.cs:527
  at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbCommand.cs:128
  at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbCommand.cs:145
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill (System.Data.DataTable,System.Data.IDbCommand,System.Data.CommandBehavior) [0x00022] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbDataAdapter.cs:297
  at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill (System.Data.DataTable) [0x00011] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbDataAdapter.cs:273
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill (System.Data.DataTable) 
  at PL.Dati.TabellaDati..ctor (PL.Dati.ConnessioneDB,string,string) [0x000e8] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Versioni/iOS/PL.Dati.iOS/TabellaDatiiOS.cs:26
  at PL.Dati.ConnessioneDB.EseguiSelezione (string) [0x00000] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Comune/ConnessioneDB.cs:206
  at PL.Dati.ConnessioneDB.EseguiSelezione (string,string,string,bool,int,string[]) [0x00137] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Comune/ConnessioneDB.cs:192
  at PL.Dati.ConnessioneDB.EseguiSelezione (string,string,string,int) [0x00000] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Comune/ConnessioneDB.cs:125
  at PL.Dati.ConnessioneDB.EseguiInserimentoTabellaDati (string,PL.Dati.TabellaDati,string[]) [0x0004d] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Comune/ConnessioneDB.cs:860
  at PL.Dati.ConnessioneDB.EseguiInserimentoTabellaDati (string,PL.Dati.TabellaDati) [0x00000] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Comune/ConnessioneDB.cs:828
  at iSell.Core.GestioneTrasmissioni.ElaboraFileDati (PL.Dati.ConnessioneDB,string,string) [0x00295] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Comune/Gestione/GestioneTrasmissioni.cs:681
  at iSell.Core.GestioneTrasmissioni.ElaboraDatiDownload (bool) [0x002a0] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Comune/Gestione/GestioneTrasmissioni.cs:888
  at iSell.Core.GestioneTrasmissioni.ElaboraCartellaDownload (bool,string,string) [0x0007b] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Comune/Gestione/GestioneTrasmissioni.cs:416
  at iSell.Core.GestioneTrasmissioni.ElaboraCartellaDownload (bool) [0x00000] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Comune/Gestione/GestioneTrasmissioni.cs:392
  at iSell.Core.GestoreInterfacciaTrasmissioni.RichiestaElaborazioneComando (string,object,object) [0x000c5] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Comune/Interfacce/Client/GestoreInterfacciaTrasmissioni.cs:69
  at iSell.Core.RicevitoreComandi.RichiediElaborazioneComando () [0x00036] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Comune/EngineDati/RicevitoreComandi.cs:97
  at iSell.Core.RicevitoreComandi.RichiediElaborazioneComando (object) [0x00007] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Comune/EngineDati/RicevitoreComandi.cs:111
  at iSell.Core.GestoreInterfacciaVisualizzazioneSorgenteDati.NotificaChiusuraInterfaccia (iSell.Core.GestioneInterfacce/TipiChiusuraInterfaccia) [0x00012] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Comune/Interfacce/Interazione utente/GestoreInterfacciaVisualizzazioneSorgenteDati.cs:54
  at iSell.OS.ViewControllerStandard.ChiudiInterfaccia (iSell.Core.GestioneInterfacce/TipiChiusuraInterfaccia) [0x0009e] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Versioni/iSelliOS/iOS/Interfaccie/Classi ausiliarie/ViewControllerStandard.cs:319
  at iSell.OS.ViewControllerStandard.ChiudiInterfaccia () [0x000a1] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Versioni/iSelliOS/iOS/Interfaccie/Classi ausiliarie/ViewControllerStandard.cs:277
  at iSell.OS.ViewControllerStandard.Handle_GestoreInterfacciaStandardhandleRichiestaChiusuraInterfaccia () [0x00000] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Versioni/iSelliOS/iOS/Interfaccie/Classi ausiliarie/ViewControllerStandard.cs:62
  at iSell.Core.GestoreInterfacciaStandard.ChiudiInterfaccia () [0x0000b] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Comune/Interfacce/Client/GestoreInterfacciaStandard.cs:77
  at iSell.Core.GestoreInterfacciaVisualizzazioneSorgenteDati.Handle_SorgenteDatiInVisualizzazionehandleIndiceElementoDatiCorrenteInSezioneModificato (PL.Dati.SorgenteDati,PL.Dati.IndiceElementoDati) [0x0004b] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Comune/Interfacce/Interazione utente/GestoreInterfacciaVisualizzazioneSorgenteDati.cs:39
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) .invoke_void_*this***SorgenteDati_IndiceElementoDati (PL.Dati.SorgenteDati,PL.Dati.IndiceElementoDati) 
  at PL.Dati.SorgenteDati.HandleIndiceElementoDatiCorrenteInSezioneModificato (PL.Dati.SezioneSorgenteDati,int) [0x00026] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Comune/SorgenteDati.cs:145
  at PL.Dati.SezioneSorgenteDati.HandleIndiceElementoDatiCorrenteModificato (PL.Dati.SezioneSorgenteDati,int) [0x0000b] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Comune/SezioneSorgenteDati.cs:143
  at PL.Dati.SezioneSorgenteDati.ImpostaIndiceElementoDatiCorrente (int,bool) [0x000e2] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Comune/SezioneSorgenteDati.cs:723
  at PL.Dati.SorgenteDati.ImpostaIndiceElementoDatiCorrenteInSezione (int,int,bool) [0x00063] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Comune/SorgenteDati.cs:616
  at PL.Dati.SorgenteDati.ImpostaIndiceElementoDatiCorrenteInSezione (int,int) [0x00000] in /Sviluppo/Librerie/Gestione Dati/PL.Dati.Mobile/Comune/SorgenteDati.cs:594
  at iSell.OS.SorgenteTableViewStandard.RowSelected (MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView,MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath) [0x00000] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Versioni/iSelliOS/iOS/Interfaccie/Classi ausiliarie/SorgenteTableViewStandard.cs:298
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void__this**_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) 
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:43
  at iSell.OS.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Sviluppo/Procedure/iSell/Versioni/iSelliOS/Main.cs:13
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)

Native stacktrace:

```
0   iSell                               0x0007b09c mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   iSell                               0x00004f38 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9c3ba59b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x04284f81 sqlite3ExprAlloc + 257
5   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x04284a5b selectExpander + 2859
6   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x042817d8 sqlite3WalkSelect + 104
7   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x04280b0c sqlite3SelectPrep + 76
8   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x0426d448 sqlite3Select + 424
9   libsqlite3.dylib                    0x04261cdd yy_reduce + 8301
10  libsqlite3.dylib                    0x0425f535 sqlite3Parser + 245
11  libsqlite3.dylib                    0x042264ac sqlite3RunParser + 396
12  libsqlite3.dylib                    0x042a50fa sqlite3Prepare + 634
13  libsqlite3.dylib                    0x0422564e sqlite3LockAndPrepare + 270
14  libsqlite3.dylib                    0x04225205 sqlite3_prepare + 53
15  ???                                 0x19ef1687 0x0 + 435099271
16  ???                                 0x19ef0960 0x0 + 435095904
17  ???                                 0x19ef0455 0x0 + 435094613
18  ???                                 0x19ef0164 0x0 + 435093860
19  ???                                 0x19ef00e4 0x0 + 435093732
20  ???                                 0x19eefaa4 0x0 + 435092132
21  ???                                 0x19eef5f2 0x0 + 435090930
22  ???                                 0x19eef468 0x0 + 435090536
23  ???                                 0x19eee884 0x0 + 435087492
24  ???                                 0x19ef8ea8 0x0 + 435130024
25  ???                                 0x19ef8e63 0x0 + 435129955
26  ???                                 0x19ef8e10 0x0 + 435129872
27  ???                                 0x19ef8cab 0x0 + 435129515
28  ???                                 0x19ef8946 0x0 + 435128646
29  ???                                 0x19ef8864 0x0 + 435128420
30  ???                                 0x19ef7c40 0x0 + 435125312
31  ???                                 0x19ef76c4 0x0 + 435123908
32  ???                                 0x1a1c9c04 0x0 + 438082564
33  ???                                 0x1a1c9770 0x0 + 438081392
34  ???                                 0x1cb20058 0x0 + 481427544
35  ???                                 0x1cb1fd7c 0x0 + 481426812
36  ???                                 0x1c8c6610 0x0 + 478963216
37  ???                                 0x19e990e8 0x0 + 434737384
38  ???                                 0x19e9470c 0x0 + 434718476
39  ???                                 0x19e94494 0x0 + 434717844
40  ???                                 0x1c7dcd8c 0x0 + 478006668
41  ???                                 0x1c7dc8d8 0x0 + 478005464
42  ???                                 0x1c7dc7c8 0x0 + 478005192
43  ???                                 0x1c7dc6a8 0x0 + 478004904
44  ???                                 0x1c7db70b 0x0 + 478000907
45  ???                                 0x1c7dd755 0x0 + 478009173
46  ???                                 0x1c7dd4cf 0x0 + 478008527
47  ???                                 0x1c7dd46e 0x0 + 478008430
48  ???                                 0x1c7dd413 0x0 + 478008339
49  ???                                 0x1a1ef511 0x0 + 438236433
50  ???                                 0x1a1eef87 0x0 + 438235015
51  ???                                 0x1a1eeea6 0x0 + 438234790
52  ???                                 0x1a1eedcc 0x0 + 438234572
53  ???                                 0x1a1ee91c 0x0 + 438233372
54  ???                                 0x1a1ee740 0x0 + 438232896
55  ???                                 0x1a1ee34c 0x0 + 438231884
56  ???                                 0x1a1ee6dd 0x0 + 438232797
57  iSell                               0x00009282 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
58  iSell                               0x00152a8e mono_runtime_invoke + 126
59  iSell                               0x00200ff6 monotouch_trampoline + 3686
60  UIKit                               0x019fb285 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1194
61  UIKit                               0x019fb4ed -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 201
62  Foundation                          0x00a415b3 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 380
63  CoreFoundation                      0x03e81376 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
64  CoreFoundation                      0x03e80e06 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 534
65  CoreFoundation                      0x03e68a82 __CFRunLoopRun + 1810
66  CoreFoundation                      0x03e67f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
67  CoreFoundation                      0x03e67e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
68  GraphicsServices                    0x04e177e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
69  GraphicsServices                    0x04e17668 GSEventRun + 104
70  UIKit                               0x0194bffc UIApplicationMain + 1211
71  ???                                 0x0edecc8d 0x0 + 249482381
72  ???                                 0x0edec790 0x0 + 249481104
73  ???                                 0x0edec56c 0x0 + 249480556
74  ???                                 0x0edec3a4 0x0 + 249480100
75  ???                                 0x0edec516 0x0 + 249480470
76  iSell                               0x00009282 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
77  iSell                               0x00152a8e mono_runtime_invoke + 126
78  iSell                               0x00156db4 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
79  iSell                               0x00157125 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
80  iSell                               0x000641d5 mono_jit_exec + 149
81  iSell                               0x001f63a4 main + 1988
82  iSell                               0x00002be5 start + 53
83  ???                                 0x00000004 0x0 + 4
```

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

## used by your application.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What does your code look like? It will be difficult to determine anything without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might very well be a problem with the garbage collector.
Make sure you dispose and set to null your SQLCommand and reader.
Take a look at this:
http://www.aaronheise.com/2012/12/monotouch-sqlite-sigsegv/#comment-10